# MathJax formulae are not beautiful in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, worksheet-function, mathjax

I have MathJax formulae not beautiful in Chrome browser. I remember I installed something for MathML support but can't find any traces now.

**Formulae in Chrome**

[image]

**Formulae in Firefox**

[image]

**UPDATE**

There are 3 errors in Console:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

located in `miscelaneous_bindings` script in function

```
// Called by native code when a channel has been closed.
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect = function(
```

Comment: Is javascript disabled in Chrome? Are there any errors in the Developer Console? (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: See my update about errors: there are some. Javascript is on.

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshots, it looks as if MathJax is running successfully but is producing native MathML output (and you're using Chrome 23 or older).

Even though MathJax uses HTML+CSS output by default, this can be changed and will be stored as a preference in a cookie.

Try right-clicking on one of the formulas to trigger the MathJax context menu where you change the rendering mechanism back to the default HTML-CSS (or the SVG-output).

Deleting the MathJax cookie should help, too.

Comment: I should add: the reason why MathJax is clearly running is that the first formula is originally LaTeX code. Also, MathJax creates a warning popup before switching to MathML output and setting the cookie. Did you get that?

Comment: So this is Chrome bug?

Comment: Not really a bug, more a missing feature. Chrome <24 simply does not have MathML enabled (Chrome Canary finally does starting this week, but webkit's MathML support is not very complete yet anyway, cf. Safari 5.1 and later). I would call it "user error": somebody actively changed MathJax's output mechanism via the MathJax menu -- in particular they got an alert box, warning them against it, yet they proceeded it anyway. The results are as expected and can be undone by the user via the MathJax menu.